# custom explode function for multi characters

Tags: php

I write custom explode function in PHP. It works fine for one character but how can modify this for multi character?
if you change this code use only strlen() function.

```
function myExplode($delimiter,$str){

$arr=[];
$s="";
$count=0;


for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) { 
    if ($str[$i]!=$delimiter) {
        $s=$s.$str[$i];
        if (!isset($str[$i+1])) {
            $arr[$count]=$s;
            $count++;
            $s="";
        }
    }
    else{
        $arr[$count]=$s;
        $count++;
        $s="";
    }

}
    return $arr;

}

$hello="Hello World,this is me";
$explodedArr=myExplode("is",$hello);

print_r($explodedArr);
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a regular expression?

Comment: Why write it custom when it already exists?